# string parameter and SELECT prepared statement for sql in java

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

i have a problem >>

programming language: java
Data base: Mysql database

i write a java code for retrive the record from the database based on the data parameters comping from the method>>

the code is:

```
public static void Get_patient_data(String Hospital1_ID,String Hospital2_ID {       
   try {
      Connection con = getConnection2();
      PreparedStatement statement = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement)
         con.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT PatientGender "+
            "FROM patientcorepopulatedtable "+
               "WHERE PatientID = Hospital1_ID LIMIT 1" );
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
      ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
      while( result.next()) {
         System.out.print("the patient Gender is"  +
            result.getString("PatientGender"));
      }
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error"+e);
   }
}
```

As you see the problem is Hospital1_ID parameter .. is coming from the method and the patientID is a column in a table patientcorepopulatedtable  ...

the `=` equal operator doesn't work.

Comment: If `Hospital1_ID` is parameter you need to put it outside the apostrophes `"WHERE PatientID =" + Hospital1_ID  +  " LIMIT 1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
PreparedStatement statement = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement)
   con.prepareStatement(
      "SELECT PatientGender FROM patientcorepopulatedtable "+
         "WHERE PatientID = ? LIMIT 1");
statement.setString(1, Hospital1_ID);
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

you can find more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String query =
   "SELECT PatientGender FROM patientcorepopulatedtable "+
      " WHERE PatientID = ? LIMIT ?";
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setString   (1, Hospital1_ID);
      preparedStmt.setInt   (2, 1);
      preparedStmt.executeQuery();
```